# Play audio from a ReadableStream

Tags: javascript, stream, html5-audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

A request to a server returns an audio file streamed back as a ReadableStream.

The server might sometimes be slow, and this is why streaming is preferred over sending the whole file at once.

How would I be able to play the audio when chunks are being sent to the client?

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Create an AudioContext
2. For each chunk, read it from body.getReader().read()
3. play it using AudioContext.decodeAudioData

Doesn't work, as decodeAudioData requires a proper file with all the chunks that come before it

Comment: What codec and container are you using for your audio stream?

Comment: mostly it is mp3, but some streams may be opus on webm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @bittere In that case, you should be able to use MediaSource Extensions to handle this.

Comment: Can't you just use a plain old audio element? Just set the src attribute and you should be fine, as long as your stream is in one of the many supported audio formats.